# firebase.firestore().collection("attendance") returns 0 result in firestore database

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### [Question updated]

**node.js code**

```
const updateLoggedMeetings = function () {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let query = store.collection("attendance");
    query.get()
    .then(data => {
      console.log("DATA is  ", data._size);
      }).catch(err => console.log("SOME ERROR OCCURED IN THEN BLOCK ",err));
    res(`blah`);
   })
 }
```

**and output screenshot**
[image: output]

### my database structure is:

1: attendance collection
[image: attendance collection]

2: meetings collection
[image: meeting collection]

my database query is:
`firebase.firestore().collection("attendance")`
when I run this query, it returns zero result.
However when I run `firebase.firestore().collection("meetings")`, it returns some result.
What I want to achieve is to retrieve document names of all the documents in `attendance` collection. Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here for us to efficiently help. Please edit your question to include the [minimal complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also clearly describe what happen when you run/debug that code, if any error messages appear, etc.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my question. I have provided the code and output screenshot of the returned result.

Comment: Don't user internal data structures please: `console.log("DATA is  ", data._size)`. Calling `get()` gives you a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot), which has a **public** [`size` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#size). So this is the equivalent using only public APIs: `console.log("DATA is  ", data.size)`

Comment: Alright, but the question remains the same. There are documents inside ```attendance``` collection but the query returns ```data.size = 0```.

Comment: You're reading the `meetings` collection in the code you shared, but that also seems to contain data. I'm not sure why that isn't being retrieved.

Comment: oops sorry, edited the code now. Actually, when I read ```meeting``` collection it returns some result. But when I query ```attendance``` collection, It returns `data.size = 0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179827/discussion-between-usama-tahir-and-frank-van-puffelen).

Answer (score 4):

You are reading a collection in which all documents are marked as deleted.

In the screenshot showing your attendances, all records are displayed in italic, which means they were deleted without deleting their sub collections.
In this case, the meetings_logged subcollection probably has records which are still present, BUT the attendance parent records are marked as deleted.
You therefore are not able to query the attendance collection while its records are displayed in the console.

This could have happened because of a trigger set in the Cloud Functions for example.

Comment: great answer! really, I am finding an answer from last two days that collections are displaying in Firestore and I'm unable to retrieve it on my end. Observation for "Italic" is great. thanks

Comment: That's wrong. They are not italics coz they're deleted, its because they don't have fields but only sub collections. I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because attendance has nested collection again so it will not return the document. You can refer this one for better understanding.
you can use like this

```
var attendance = 
db.collection('attendance').doc('doc_id') and you will get the logged_meeting
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model

Comment: so is there any workaround to retrieve document names of ```attendance``` collection?

Comment: you can use db.collection('attendance').doc('doc_id') and you will get the meeting_logged

Comment: the problem is I don't know the ```doc_id```. That is why I want to first get all document ids and then write another query to retrieve ```logged_meeting``` for each ```doc_id```

Comment: app = firebase.initializeApp(fireBaseConfig);  
let docRef = firebase.firestore(app).collection("favorite")
        .where('category', '==', category)
        .where('uid', '==', userId)
        .where('page', '==', page);
      docRef.get()

Comment: i used above configuration in my firebase aplication